# IIB Error Log - Dequeued failed message. Propagating a message to the failure terminal

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I am new to IIB technology, I am facing an issue and seeing below error very frequently when there is failure in the messageflow.
We have MQ input node which all terminals are connected, Failure and Catch terminals are connected to CommonErrorHandling in which it route the message to backout queue.
Have verified backout queue which is created and present, Can someone help me provide some insights.

```
Message flow - MQ Input Node(Domain-JSON) ->Compute ->Https Request node

    <Catalog>BIPmsgs</Catalog>
    <Severity>3</Severity>
    <Number>2652</Number>
    <Text>Dequeued failed message. Propagating a message to the failure terminal</Text>
```

Debugged the flow and could observe it is coming out from the Failure terminal of Input MQ node but not able to understand much why it is giving this message.

Answer (score 0):

Please share more details about your flow. From which node is the exception happening at first ? Did you check the MQOutput node configuration ?
It is also helpful to connect a trace node to the failure or catch terminals of the MQOutput node. It should give a clearer description of why its bombing out before rolling the message all the way back to the MQInput node.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JSON String for instance control the type of variable.
In IIB it's necessary control everything step by step.